# How do I access foreign table data within a repeater

Tags: asp.net

I have my `Items` table bound to the repeater control. What if I want to display data from another table that is related to this one?

I'm using LINQ to SQL as the datasource in the codebehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the repeater [itemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) event get any data you need with LINQ and display what you need.